# My system requirements to install ubuntu-16.04 doesn't match completely with the recommended requirements, can I still install it on my system?

Tags: system-installation

According to the system requirements to install Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, 
processor should be 2 GHz dual core processor, but my computer has 1.7 Ghz dual core processor.Can I install that even if it does not match the recommended system requirements or should I install some other version?

I am following [this installation guide on ubuntu.com](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop). I am new to Ubuntu installation, your help will be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you try Lubuntu https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lubuntu#Lubuntu_16.04_LTS , its lightweight and fast.

Comment: @digiwizkid Thanks for the suggestion, I really appreciate it. But I am trying to install Ubuntu on my machine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I find out which version and derivative of Ubuntu is right for my hardware in terms of minimal system requirements?](/q/206407/175814)

Answer (score 3):

Yes. yes you can.

Ubuntu isn't that demanding of a system and especially not when compared to Windows, I.E. : any Windows release version is less ressource intensive then any ubuntu release version.

In the case of less ram and less graphic power such as say a 2-4GB RAM netbook with and intel atom and graphics ran off the atom I'd highly recommend another ubuntu flavour : say https://ubuntu-mate.org/download/

Comment: My system has 8GB RAM, so I hope there would not be much problem.

Comment: you have my green flag ubuntu shoul purr on your machine. make sure you run of set of "first to-do's" once your ubuntu is up and running such as enabling "partners" in "software sources" and running updates and reboot before you install anything. is your processor 64bit?

Comment: remember to upvote and mark as solution - thanks!

Comment: dang I was writing when he posted before me :)

Comment: I thought the same thing! :-) anyways high five we both did it!

Answer (score 0):

should work those are recommended system requirements not min. system requirements, but cant say for how performance will be since its bellow what is recommend by Ubuntu. I would be more concerned if you didn't meet ram requirements then 300 mhz cpu speed.

Be sure to run the live version off a dvd or usb first before dedicating to a full install if its possible. If performance is satisfactory the full install will be better then the live cd experience.